# Ask for an alternative algorithm of Felzenszwalb's graph-based segmentation cost less time(e.g parallel one) but produce not much worse effect as it

Tags: image, algorithm, segment

Felzenszwalb's graph based image segmentation algorithm is too classical one that many have adopted and compared with.

Now requirements seek an alternative one cost less time(can be a paralle one) but produce a result almost as good as Felzenszwalb's one or not much worse than it.

Felzenszwalb's graph-base image segmentation algorithm is from his paper, "Efficient Graph-Based Image Segmentation". http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/segment/

Comment: That paper is not recent at this point. Have you tried looking through the papers that cite it?

Comment: I have skimmmed several paper cited it. Quite a lot of ones. "Real-time image segmentation on a GPU"(ref 22). "Efficient organized point cloud segmentation with connected components"(ref 15). "Parallel k-means image segmentation using sort, scan and connected components on a GPU"(ref 12).

Comment: "Parallel Image Segmentation Using Reduction-Sweeps on Multicore Processors and GPUs"(ref 3). "Image segmentation using normalized cuts and efficient graph-based segmentation"(ref 3). "An Optimized image Segmentation Algorithm"(ref 3). "Fast Segmentation via Randomized Hashing"(ref 4).

Comment: "Efficient image segmentation algorithm using SLIC superpixels and boundary-focused region merging"(ref 3). "New accelerated graph-based method of image segmentation applying minimum spanning tree"(ref ?). But I have no idea of which is most appropriate for me.

Comment: If only there is already an implementation of the proposed algorithm preferably compatible on linux.

Comment: Hey, David Eisenstat! Have you already lost interest of my topic?

Comment: I'm not at all knowledgeable about the practical side of this topic. As a researcher, I was interested in this work because there's a linear-time algorithm for planar-graph MST, the apparent bottleneck, but I never got around to trying that out. There's probably another Stack Exchange site with more domain experts, but I couldn't tell you which one.